# Getting an Embed Token for Power BI Report with Row Level Security for a Specific User

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am attempting to make calls to the Power BI API to get an embed token for a report that uses row level security.

The specific endpoint I am using is:

https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/*workspace_id*/reports/*report_id*/GenerateToken

The body of the request looks something like this:

```
{
    "accessLevel": "View",
    "identities":
    [
        {
            "username": "username",
            "roles":
            [
            ],
            "datasets":
            [
                "dataset_id"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If I specify anything other than the GUID of the service principal that I use to obtain the initial access token for the username in the request body (above), I get the following message with a 403 response:

Creating embed token for accessing dataset *dataset_id* requires effective identity username to be identical to the caller's principal name

If I use the GUID of the service principal, I get an embed token with a 200 response.

My understanding is that since the app that is going to embed the Power BI objects performs the authentication, I should be able to pass anything for the username in the request body. However, I am unable to do so at the moment. I suspect this is a setting that needs to be made somewhere but I am not sure where to make such a setting (if this is the case).

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Did you

"Enable Embed content in apps either for the entire organization or for the specific security group you created in Azure AD."

?

[image]

[Embed Power BI content with service principal and an application secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal#how-to-get-the-service-principal-object-id)